# How to include submit input and button values with jQuery form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I just realized that serializeArray() will not include submit input and submit button values per http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/

> No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted
>   using a button.

What is the cleanest way to include the button value in the form submission?

http://jsfiddle.net/QJz35/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                $("#myForm").submit(function(){
                    var inputs=$(this).find(":input");
                    var inputs_serial=inputs.serializeArray();
                    console.log(this,inputs,inputs_serial);
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="myForm">
            <input name="text" value="text" type="text">
            <button name="task" value="MyTask" type="submit">My Task</button>
            <input name="task" value="MyTask" type="submit">
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need the button value? Can you just create a hidden `input` in your form and use that?

Comment: @Shaded.  Yes if I only have one submit button.  If two, then I could put an event on both buttons to set the value of the hidden input.  Is this the cleanest way of doing this?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would do, just have a common hidden input and have the buttons assign their value to it `onclick` or something along those lines.

Comment: If your putting the button into an array anyway, why not loop through it and return the innerHTML of inputs? Maybe I am not understanding what you truly want though.